# jquery ajax call is forcing response to lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am making a AJAX Call from my .net Application in below manner

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '@Url.Action("GetRouteUsingJobId", "Home")',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       dataType: "json",
       data: JSON.stringify({ "jobid": jobid }),
         success: function (result) {
           var response = result.result;
           var RouteArray = response.eSRIRouteResponse.features;
           //RouteArray = response.eSRIRouteResponse.Features; //ERROR
         },
         error: function (request, status, error) {
           alert('Error: Unable To Get Route details.');
         }
});
```

When I am trying to access Features from eSRIRouteResponse like below it is giving error

```
var RouteArray = response.eSRIRouteResponse.Features; //ERROR
```

But this working

```
var RouteArray = response.eSRIRouteResponse.features;
```

From my MVC Controller I am returning like below

```
ESRIRouteResponse eSRIRouteResponse=Some Value;
return Json(new { eSRIRouteResponse },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And my model class contains eSRIRouteResponse like below

```
public class ESRIRouteResponse
{
    public Features Features{ get; set; }
}
```

I am using JQUERY 3.2.1

What is the issue,How to rectify ?

Comment: Are you using Json.NET? If so refer [MVC now serializes JSON with camel case names by default](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194)

Answer (score 0):

```
RouteArray = response.eSRIRouteResponse.features;
```

you are basically accessing the other attributes inside the response. The response contains the data that has been sent back from the action. You cannot directly access your model properties in the response.

So,

```
RouteArray = response.eSRIRouteResponse.Features;
```

the above won't work.

Comment: check question coorectly,what I am asking for,more ever we can directly access your model properties in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to remove `dataType: "json"` and parse the response manually.

```
     success: function (result) {
       var response = JSON.parse(result);
       RouteArray = response.eSRIRouteResponse.Features;
     },
```